# Unautop / Sanitize content added to a post through a plugin

Tags: posts, content, formatting

I am using the SimpleReach plugin that adds some content to every post using the content hook. The content that is being added is

```
<!-- SimpleReach Slide Plugin Version: {{srslide_plugin_version}} -->
<script type='text/javascript' id='simplereach-slide-tag'>
    __reach_config = {
      pid: '{{srslide_pid}}',
      title: '{{title}}',
      tags: {{{tags}}},
      authors: {{{authors}}},
      channels: {{{channels}}},{{slide_logo_elem}}
      slide_active: {{srslide_disable_on_post}},{{slide_icon_elem}}
      date: '{{published_date}}',
      url: '{{canonical_url}}',
      header: '{{srslide_header_text}}'
    };
    var content = document.getElementById('simplereach-slide-tag').parentNode, loc;
    if (content.className){ loc = '.' + content.className; }
    if (content.id){ loc = '#' + content.id; }
    __reach_config.loc = loc || content;
    (function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.async = true;
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = document.location.protocol + '//d8rk54i4mohrb.cloudfront.net/js/slide.js';
      __reach_config.css = '{{srslide_css_url}}';
      var tg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      if (!tg) {tg = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];}
      if (tg) {tg.appendChild(s);}
    })();
</script>
```

However Wordpress is sanitizing the content by adding extra breaks and paragraphs before and after.

I want to disable autop only for this content so that breaks/paragraphs aren't added.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of *caveats* before beginning. It tried to run that plugin but apparently I have to register with a third party site before I can use it, so that throws a wrench in testing.

Second, I am having trouble duplicating this problem. That may be because I have beaten my dev stack up too much and it is time to wipe it clean and start over (which it is), so that said...

`wpautop` runs on the entire post content. You can't, by any means that I am aware, restrict it to run on only part of the content.

I have not installed and tested that plugin so I can't confirm that your analysis of the problem is correct, but in general there are several things that you can do to avoid having `wpautop` mangle content:

1. Register and enqueue the script so as to avoid shoving this into the
   post body at all.
2. Remove all the line breaks and extra whitespace from that block of
   code. None of that is necessary and without it `wpautop` would have
   nothing to bite into.
3. Insert the content very late via a priority when the callback is
   added to `the_content`

The only one that you may be able to effect is #3. The script adds that code by means of: `add_filter('the_content', 'srslide_insert_slide_js');`. You should be able to remove that with `remove_filter('the_content', 'srslide_insert_slide_js');` and add it back with `add_filter('the_content', 'srslide_insert_slide_js',1000);` to get it to run after `wpautop`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am reading your answer now but I did it the same way you described. Sorry about the testing part, this plugin was already installed on client's website and I was directly working on the live site (I know its bad).

I just modified the plugins code to `add_filter('the_content', 'srslide_insert_slide_js', 999);`

Comment: You marked this as accepted. I assume what you did to fix the problem was suggestion #3?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can setup autop like this.

The only idea that comes to my mind is to set a post meta after you insert the post and then setup a condition in functions.php.

I don't know how the post is added by that plugin, but you will need to retrieve its ID.

Then use this to add the meta:

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, 'no_autop', 'true'); ?>
```

Then disable autop on posts with that meta by adding this to functions.php:

```
if(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'no_autop', true )=='') {
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
```